# Is there some way to filter YouTube channel subscriptions list?

Tags: youtube

I have like 150 YouTube channel subscriptions, and the quick bar (to the left) will show them all, but I don't actually watch them all.

So my question is if there is some way to limit the amount of channels that show on that quick bar? I would prefer to only show the ones I want also, the ones I really like most than all others.

Answer (score 1):

There is this javascript that requires Greasemonkey or Tampermonkey:
https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/12926-simple-youtube-channel-subscriptions-filter-in

It simple and does only that.
I still wonder if there are alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

I made a script that you can use to filter out some videos based on video title:
https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/16771-filter-youtube-subscriptions-videos

Comment: Adding script contents here would more helpful for future readers.

Comment: @serenesat these scripts are actually like plugins/applications, the problem on copying it here I think, is that users may miss updates, also this one is under GPLv3, and content here is CC-BY-SA-3.0, not sure if they are compatible?

Comment: @SergeyLarionov your script will hide the specified videos right? my problem was that my "channel subscriptions" list was unnecessarily big, I needed it shrinked to the favorite channels. I want to subscribe to as manny channels I want, but I will only really follow a handful. For tagging watched videos for ex. I use the [Better YouTube Watch History extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/better-youtube-watch-hist/lleajdkalfbohpinoaekajagdefaeckd/reviews?hl=en)

Comment: @SergeyLarionov and for hiding the watched videos I can use [this script](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/review/149842), but I actually use another script that just shrink the watched video, here: https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/16868-youtube-shrink-watched-youtube-videos